# .txt files become empty

Tags: python, linux, raspbian-jessie

I have few .txt files I use to store configuration information for some python and shell scripts on my Pi. They are occasionally read from and very rarely written to. The Pi runs 24/7 mostly but will occasionally be unplugged from power so I can move it to a new location. I have noticed that sometimes the .txt files would suddenly become empty. Any idea what causes this? How it can be prevented?

Comment: What does unplug mean? Unplug from power, ethernet, wifi, USB storage ...? Or from all to move the RasPi? How do you unplug it from power? Never do it before a graceful shutdown by software.

Comment: @Ingo the Pi is enclosed securely and running an automated script. I am unable to securely shutdown from SW. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set up auto-save since I see that you mention "very rarely written to". I'm not sure what the bug is, but I suggest that you may want to save the file more frequently and set a backup (or a copy of the file) in case there are errors again.

Comment: So you suggest creating a copy of the file and save the original to the copy frequently? and load the copy to the original every reboot/system startup?

Comment: I think so. Also just a "backup" solution in case there is data corruption.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like some files that are open/being read during shutdown may become corrupted and wiped. An easy solution is to include a button on the enclosure you are using that registers an interrupt and can issue a shutdown command to the RPi. [This](https://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-3) link describes how to implement an interrupt using one button and a few lines of python. I would also use the `os` library and the classic `sudo reboot now` or `sudo shutdown` command.

As also suggested, adding a cron job that backs up the files periodically isn't a bad idea. An `@reboot ...` line can also be added to your crontab to check if the file is empty and recover the last backup.